# How do i fix this loop to display images from my database using bootstrap carousel

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap-4

I tried using bootstrap carousel to display images from my database but something seem to be wrong with my loop...

```
<?php
  $message = "";
  if(empty($_GET['id'])) {
    $session->message("<div class='btn sm-warning'>please select an image.</div>");
    redirect_to('list_properties.php');
  } 
  $id      = $_GET['id'];
  $sql     = "SELECT * FROM pictures2 WHERE photograph_id='$id';";
  $photos = Picture::find_by_sql($sql);
?>
```

The fetch is all correct from the database but the loop displaying the images in the slide displays one image and the slide loops between the first and second slide only.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide mx-auto" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <?php 
     $i=0;
    if(count($photos)){
        foreach ($photos as $photo) {
            if($i==0){
                echo '<li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>';
                $i++;
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0"></li>';
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
   ?>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
   <?php
    $a=0;
    if(count($photos)){
        foreach ($photos as $photo) {
            if($a==0){
                ?>
            <div class="carousel-item active">
           <img src="<?php echo $photo->image_path(); ?>" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive"  alt="<?php echo $photo->title; ?>"/>
            <?php   
                $a++;
            }else
            ?>
    </div>
           <?php
            {
                ?>
            <div class="carousel-item">
           <img src="<?php echo $photo->image_path(); ?>" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $photo->title; ?>"/>
               <?php
                $a++;
            }
            ?>
    </div>
       <?php
        }
    }
   ?>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: why are you incrementing `$i++,$a++` two times in `foreach` why not after the if..else and add data-slid-to="'.$i/'"

Comment: data-slide-to="0"    add the index.

Comment: You should definitely use prepared statements, as your code is open to SQL injections. Additionally, what have you tried to debug the problem? Generating markup is not that hard to debug

Comment: @M.Hemant i did that but loop still the same

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $message = "";
  if(empty($_GET['id'])) {
    $session->message("<div class='btn sm-warning'>please select an image.</div>");
    redirect_to('list_properties.php');
  } 
  $id      = $_GET['id'];
  $sql     = "SELECT * FROM pictures2 WHERE photograph_id='$id';";
  $photos = Picture::find_by_sql($sql);
?>
```

.

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
 <?php
$i = 0; 
 foreach($photos as $photo){
        if($i == 0){
?>
<li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="<?php echo $i; ?>" class="active"></li>
<?php
 $i++;  }else{
    if($i != 0){        
?>
<li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="<?php echo $i; ?>" ></li>
<?php               
        } $i++;
    }
 }
?> 
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
   <?php 
    $i = 0;  
    foreach($photos as $photo){
        if($i == 0){
    ?>
    <div class="carousel-item active">
    <img src="<?php echo $photo->image_path(); ?>" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" height="500" width="500" alt="<?php echo $photo->title; ?>"/>
    </div>
    <?php               
    $i++;   } else{
        if($i != 0){    
    ?>
    <div class="carousel-item">
    <img src="<?php echo $photo->image_path(); ?>" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" height="500" width="500" alt="<?php echo $photo->title; ?>"/>
    </div>
        <?php                           
        } $i++;
    }  
      }
    ?>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```