# How to use foreach loop to display images in bootstrap carousel?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach-loop-container

I want to display images using bootstrap carousel using foreach loop.

I have been having a difficult time trying to display images using foreach loop... Please note that my database functions are not the problem... I just need help to restructure the loop.

```
<?php
  $message = "";
  if(empty($_GET['id'])) {
    $session->message("<div class='btn sm-warning'>please select an image.</div>");
    redirect_to('list_properties.php');
  } 
  $id      = $_GET['id'];
  $sql     = "SELECT * FROM pictures2 WHERE photograph_id='$id';";
  $photos = Picture::find_by_sql($sql);
?>
```

Truth is i am so confused right now. I just want to restructure this loop using foreach...

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide mx-auto" data-ride="carousel">
 <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <?php $i=0; foreach($photos as $photo){?>
      <?php if($i==0){ ?><li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="<?php echo $i; ?>" class="active"><?php } ?>
       <?php if($i % 2 == 0){ ?><li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php }?>
       <?php if($i % 4 != 0){ ?></li><?php }?>
       <?php $i++; } ?>
      </li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <?php $i=0; foreach($photos as $photo){?>
         <?php if($i==0){ ?><div class="carousel-item active"><?php } ?>
             <?php if($i % 2 == 0){ ?><div class="carousel-item"><?php }?>
          <div class="col-xs-3">
       <img src="<?php echo $photo->image_path(); ?>" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" height="500" width="500" alt=""/>
           </div>
                <?php if($i % 4 != 0){ ?></div><?php }?>
                <?php $i++; } ?>
                 </div>
     </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a> 
</div>
```

Comment: what's the output from your loop?

Comment: How is this different from your previous question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55953068/ …? Please don’t create duplicates on the same topic, but continue the discussion within the existing question.

Comment: Why do you want to use `foreach` loop. You are already using an extra variable `$i` to do some calculation, so you can use the normal for loop.

Comment: And there’s also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55947452/, so this is basically the third time you are asking this now.

Comment: to follow on from @RopAliMunshi you could also user foreach($photos as $key => $photo) and then use use the key to work out the position to save an extra variable and doing any counting (I'm assuming it's a normal indexed array).  Either way this code is difficult to read and you could easily simplify it by just having a php block and concatenating the content as a string, removing all the opening and closing tags which make it seem more complicated than it (probably) is

Comment: @jameson2012  i have 6 images so far in my sql but it displays 4... i want a dynamic loop display that even if i have 19 images, it should display all... The indicators are working right too

Comment: yeah, but the reason I'm asking for your output is because I suspect you're closing divs at the Wong point so the output is there it's just nested somewhere.  but anyway, as @04FS says you need to carry this on in your original question

Comment: @04FS previous question was using a forloop, i didnt get any solution so i decided to use foreach

Comment: @RopAliMunshi help me rewrite

Comment: @jameson2012 help me rewrite the code please.

Comment: _“previous question was using a forloop, i didnt get any solution so i decided to use foreach”_ - the difference between the two is rather minimal. And besides that, it is not really clear what you are even trying to ask here - _“I just want to restructure this loop using foreach...”_ - well, then do so … what’s stopping you? Please go read [ask]. We expect a proper problem description from you here, not just a description of what you _want_ to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
     <?php
      $message = "";
      if(empty($_GET['id'])) {
        $session->message("<div class='btn sm-warning'>please select an image.</div>");
        redirect_to('list_properties.php');
      } 
      $id      = $_GET['id'];
      $sql     = "SELECT * FROM pictures2 WHERE photograph_id='$id';";
      $photos = Picture::find_by_sql($sql);
    ?>


  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
     <?php
    $i = 0; 
     foreach($photos as $photo){
            if($i == 0){
    ?>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="<?php echo $i; ?>" class="active"></li>
    <?php
     $i++;  }else{
        if($i != 0){        
    ?>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="<?php echo $i; ?>" ></li>
    <?php               
            } $i++;
        }
     }
    ?> 
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
       <?php 
        $i = 0;  
        foreach($photos as $photo){
            if($i == 0){
        ?>
        <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="<?php echo $photo->image_path(); ?>" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" height="500" width="500" alt="<?php echo $photo->title; ?>"/>
        </div>
        <?php               
        $i++;   } else{
            if($i != 0){    
        ?>
        <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="<?php echo $photo->image_path(); ?>" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" height="500" width="500" alt="<?php echo $photo->title; ?>"/>
        </div>
            <?php                           
            } $i++;
        }  
          }
        ?>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
```